# flexbox is setting all of my text side by side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some weird behavior going on in my divs at the moment, each div is written like the other (they are just mirror images). The text is mimicking columns and is setting side by side instead of top to bottom like it should. The oddest thing is, it seems to be working fine on another page this particular page only contains the behavior.

The code is something like this

```
<div class="flex-wrap">

    <div class="flex">
        <h3>A title</h3>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
        <h3>A title</h3>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>

</div>

<style>
.flex-wrap{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.flex{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

I've taken this apart piece by piece in the inspector tool and I'm even more baffled as to why it works fine on one page and not at all on another. The last section uses the same css layout it just contains a different picture and text. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? BONUS POINTS IF YOU CAN TELL ME WHY.

Comment: Those two pages do not use the same layout and classes.

Comment: The "last section" is of the tours page is identical

Comment: Remove `.tours-sec-3-p2-wrap` from the wrapper of the text/content on the spirits page OR in that class you can add `flex-direction: column`

Comment: I get what you're saying, the whole reasoning behind the way it was setup was so that the content would always be centered with the picture set beside it (or visa versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite anyone's belief, the layouts of each section are exactly the same. They are generated with the cms, they are not static pages.

That said, the behavior was only different between the 2 because of the length of the content in each flex container. Adding the same content to the tours page created the same behavior.

The problem was indeed solved with flex-direction: column; and additionally adding justify-content: center;

Comment: Someone already posted an answer with the `flex-direction: column;` solution for you, so it is not appropriate to simply post one yourself with the very same. I recommend you delete this answer, and, if needed, add a comment to the given answer with any additional clarifications, and also reward the promised points...and an accept

Comment: They didn't solve the problem and didn't explain why

Comment: Michael_B said you could use `flex-direction: column`, which you said yourself in your own answer solved the issue, so not much to talk about, so down votes from me for this behavior.

Comment: it doesn't solve the whole problem just part of it. if I get 500000000 down votes I don't care, setting this to display:block would do that. He and everyone else who commented stated that each section was different beyond the content, I already knew that setting it to column would fix that part, did it center the content though in a way that looked clean and consistent on every page? NO

Comment: If you solve a problem on one page and break everything on 8 other pages it really doesn't do any good does it?

Comment: Huh?....you ask ***flexbox is setting all of my text side by side***, and get an answer how to make them flow vertical, which you now say you already knew?? And then you start talking about ***center the text***...., where in your question did you ask for that?

Comment: It explicitly says which page has the intended behavior and which page has the undesirable behavior he just overlooked it even though I said they are the same layout, doing that broke page with the intended behavior and he wasn't even the 1st person to bring that method up. Maybe I'll put it in terms you're more used to. You went to a friend because your having trouble with your relationship. Your friend decides you're actually to blame and has now decided to take your partner. You no longer have a problem because you no longer have a partner!

Comment: @BrendanJackson, it's not that I misunderstood your question or overlooked a behavior. It's that when I delved into your code for each page, I didn't find the behaviors you were referencing. So I posted an answer based on my best assumption. That's one reason it's always good to post enough code in the question to reproduce the problem. These sorts of misunderstandings can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to keep in mind is that flex layout applies only between parent and child elements. Descendants in a flex container beyond the children do not participate in flex layout.

---

In your "broken page", the four side-by-side paragraph elements are children of a flex container (`.tours-sec-3-p2-wrap`).

```
.tours-sec-3-p2-wrap {
    padding: 2%;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    background-size: 15%;
    padding-top: 0;
    background-position: 0px 30%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-direction: row`, so the children (flex items) are lining up in a row. The quick and easy solution is to override the default with `flex-direction: column`.

---

In your "working fine" page, the image and paragraphs *are not* children of a flex container. These elements are children of a block container, and that container is the child of the flex container.

Your image and text are being aligned with float, not flex, properties.

If you want to use flex properties, add `display: flex` to the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use flex-direction: column; you can make your elements stretch to 100% width to force the wrap.

```css
.flex-wrap{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.flex{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap:wrap; /* added  */
}
.flex,
.flex h3,
.flex p
 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <div class="flex">
    <h3>A title</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <h3>A title</h3>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bonus Tip for `justify-content: center` and text aligning left after wrapping. (run the code snippet)

```css
.flex-wrap{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flex {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.text-centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <div class="flex">
    <h3>Centered (but it hasn't wrapped)</h3>
    <p>centered text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <h3>Not Centered (after wrap)</h3>
    <p>sometimes you'll want to use justify-content: center; and  keep the text centered along with whatever other elements are inside the div. You'll see in the 2nd example the text aligns left after it wraps. Add text-align: center; and it will center the text.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex text-centered">
    <h3>Centered</h3>
    <p>sometimes you'll want to use justify-content: center; and  keep the text centered along with whatever other elements are inside the div. You'll see in the 2nd example the text aligns left after it wraps. Add text-align: center; and it will center the text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```